# Get the Key of the newly inserted row using TableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

I am using a TableAdapter to insert a new row into a table. The issue is how to get the Key from the table of the newly inserted row? I have searched around a bit and find a couple of solutions:

1. Use Max() - this is widely considered a terrible idea.
2. Add SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to the query. When I do this I get errors in the SqlBuilder. When I try this solution I get:

> Must declare the scalar variable @FileName
>   FileName is the first field in my query:

```
INSERT INTO FileTable
                         (FileName, DirectoryName, FullPath, Extension, ToolNumber)
VALUES        (@FileName,@DirectoryName,@FullPath,@Extension,@ToolNumber);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

My VB.Net code:

```
Dim fileRow As ToolsDataSet.FileTableRow
fileRow = ToolsDataSet.FileTable.NewRow()

With fileRow
    .FileName = "Test13456789"
End With

ToolsDataSet.FileTable.Rows.Add(fileRow)
FileTableTableAdapter.Update(fileRow)
```

It sure seems like a common need.

How do I get that Key?

Answer (score 2):

With a Typed DataTable that is constrained to a single Table (ie: `SELECT * FROM FileTable`), the Typed DataTable is capable of noticing the `IDENTITY COLUMN` and populating it after the insert happens giving you access to it in your code.

**MSSql Test Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Insert_Test](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [aString] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [aNumber] [int] NULL,
    [aBit] [bit] NULL,
    [aDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [aFloat] [float] NULL,
    [aImage] [varbinary](2048) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Insert_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**VB.Net Test Method**

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestAddRowWithDataAdapter()
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server=.;Database=JVTest;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()

        Dim dataAdapter As New JVTestDataSetTableAdapters.Insert_TestTableAdapter()

        Dim dt As New JVTestDataSet.Insert_TestDataTable
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt)

        Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count)

        Dim newRow As JVTestDataSet.Insert_TestRow
        newRow = dt.NewInsert_TestRow()
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow)

        newRow("aString") = "abc"
        newRow("aNumber") = 123
        newRow("aDate") = DateTime.Now

        Dim rowsInserted As Integer = dataAdapter.Update(newRow)

        Dim rowId As Integer = newRow.Id

    End Using
End Sub
```

When the below line, executes it returns 1, corresponding to one row being added

```
Dim rowsInserted As Integer = dataAdapter.Update(newRow)
```

When the line below executes, the `.Id` column contains the new rows Id

```
Dim rowId As Integer = newRow.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a typed data set, there is a select command at the end of insert command to get the new values including identity column.

So it's enough to check the value of identity column, after update:

```
ToolsDataSet.FileTable.Rows.Add(fileRow)
Dim id = fileRow.Id
```